# Does stdout get stored somewhere in the filesystem or in memory?

Tags: shell, stdout, zsh

I know I can save the result of a command to a variable using `last_output=$(my_cmd)` but what I'd really want is for `$last_output` to get updated every time I run a command. Is there a variable, zsh module, or plugin that I could install?

I guess my question is does `stdout` get permanently written somewhere (at least before the next command)? That way I could manipulate the results of the previous command without having to re-run it. This would be really useful for commands that take a long time to run

Comment: **stdout** is just a file handle that by default is connected to the console, but could be redirected. You can redirect the output to be stored in a file if you want, and then manipulate that file before you show the result.

Comment: would I lose the console output if I did that? Could I redirect it to both?

Comment: You can't redirect to two places directly without overhead or side effects -- you only get output to one destination per `write()` call -- but you can redirect to a process such as `tee` which in turn writes to two places.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808597/send-output-of-last-command-to-a-file-automatically-in-bash/20809201

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run the following:

```
exec > >(tee save.txt)
# ... stuff here...
exec >/dev/tty
```

...then your stdout for everything run between the two commands will go both to stdout, and to `save.txt`.

You could, of course, write a shell function which does this for you:

```
with_saved_output() {
  "$@" \
  2> >(tee "$HOME/.last-command.err >&2) \
  | tee "$HOME/.last-command.out"
}
```

...and then use it at will:

```
with_saved_output some-command-here
```

...and zsh almost certainly will provide a mechanism to wrap interactively-entered commands. (In bash, which I can speak to more directly, you could do the same thing with a DEBUG trap).

---

However, even though you **can**, you **shouldn't** do this: When you split stdout and stderr into two streams, information about the exact ordering of writes is lost, even if those streams are recombined later.

Thus, the output

```
O: this is written to stdout first
E: this is written to stderr second
```

could become:

```
E: this is written to stderr second
O: this is written to stdout first
```

when these streams are individually passed through `tee` subprocesses to have copies written to disk. There are also buffering concerns created, and differences in behavior caused by software which checks whether it's outputting to a TTY and changes its behavior (for instance, software which turns color-coded output on when writing directly to console, and off when writing to a file or pipeline).

Answer (score 3):

**stdout** is just a file handle that by default is connected to the console, but could be redirected.

```
yourcommand > save.txt
```

If you want to display the output to the console and save it to a file at the same time yout could pipe the output to **tee**, a command that writes everything it receives on **stdin** to **stdout** and to a file of your choice:

```
yourcommand | tee save.txt
```

Comment: right, but is there a way to make this sustainable? The point is that I sometimes run a command that takes longer than I thought, and I don't want to run it again to manipulate the output

Comment: By using the built in command **exec**in zsh `exec > >(tee ~/save.txt)` you will save all output to the file save.txt at the same time as it displayed to the console. However, the save.txt will have all output, not just from the last command. I'm not aware of a way to do it for every command, without specifying it when running each command.

Comment: Sorry for the missing space above, the ** around exec is to make it bold: **exec** but because of a missing space after the last * the stars are not translated.